# List of dictionaries, and a dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a clean pandas dataframe from a list of dictionaries, in which the value of a key in a dictionary can also be a list of dictionaries.

Here is my initial list:

```
[ {'product_id':1, 
   'categories': [{'toy_id':'x1', 'sales':50}, {'toy_id':'x2', 'sales':50}], 
   'buyers': [{'buyer_id':'y1' , 'buyer_age':22}, {'buyer_id':'y2' ,'buyer_age':31}]}]
```

Initially I convert the list to a pandas dataframe

```
list_pd = pd.DataFrame(list)
```

Although this converts my list to a pandas dataframe, there are two columns called 'categories' and 'buyers' which are still a list of dictionaries. I'm not sure how to convert these columns to columns where key name is the column name and value is in the rows. My end result would look something like this:

```
____product_id____toy_id____sales____buyer_id____buyer_age

________1_________x1_______50_______y1__________22____
________1_________x2_______50_______y2__________31____
```

Here's the code I've tried (I'm trying to convert my earlier into a dataframe again, thinking maybe it will break down the dictionary):

```
list_pd_2 = pd.DataFrame(list_pd)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

once you have created `list_pd` like you did, you can use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) on both columns categories and buyers, then create a dataframe from each exploded column keeping the original index, [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) both dataframes and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to the column 'product_id' like:

```
s_cat = list_pd['categories'].explode()
s_buy = list_pd['buyers'].explode()
df_f = list_pd[['product_id']]\
              .join(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(s_cat.tolist(), index=s_cat.index), 
                               pd.DataFrame(s_buy.tolist(), index=s_buy.index)], 
                              axis=1))
print (df_f)
   product_id toy_id  sales buyer_id  buyer_age
0           1     x1     50       y1         22
0           1     x2     50       y2         31
```

Comment: @HamzaKhalid you may want to use `reset_index(drop=True)` at the end as well if you don't want to have repeated value in the index ;)

Comment: Thanks Ben. Another small addition: One of my columns is not a list of dictionaries, but a dictionary. I cannot use the explode method on this (since explode requires a list). Any idea how I can change that dictionary into seperate columns, with keys as headers?

Comment: @HamzaKhalid I guess you can do `pd.DataFrame(list_pd['col_name'].tolist(), index=list_pd.index)`?

Comment: I think the trick would be to somehow convert the dictionary into columns initially (when making list_pd) before making the pandas join?

Comment: @HamzaKhalid maybe, like this without the exact structure it is hard to tell, to many possibilities ;) maybe ask a new question

Comment: I get what you're saying now. Here's my latest code (assuming Buyers was the dictionary column I was talking about):

Comment: final_f = df_f.join(pd.concat([buyer_df, index=buyer_pd.index)], axis=1)).reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: where df_f is the pandas dataframe obtained after doing the original join as you mentioned in your solution answer

Comment: for some reason, it's not working. I'm sure its a syntax error, but I cant figure out why

Comment: It's okay if its too complicated. I know its getting blurry now. Thanks anyways for your original answer it was super helpful

Answer (score 1):

You  can make use of pandas [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) function : get two dataframes (categories and buyers) and merge back with pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
from pandas import json_normalize
categories = json_normalize(data,'categories','product_id')
buyers = json_normalize(data,'buyers')
pd.concat((categories,buyers),axis=1)

    toy_id  sales   product_id  buyer_id    buyer_age
0     x1      50       1          y1          22
1     x2      50       1          y2          31
```