# python: convert json format to tabular

Tags: python, json

If I have 2 rows of Json data, how do I make this tabular with all the columns, as some columns might not be present in one row and vice versa.

```
[{'_id': 33,
'topics': [{'q': 5, 'a': '0'},
{'q': 6, 'a': 'suf'},
{'q': 7, 'a': 'ksjkdjfkdjfkdjf'},
{'q': 8, 'a': 'janesmith@gmail.com'},
{'q': 100, 'a': 'YES'}]},
{'_id': 55,
'topics': [{'q': 1, 'a': '0'},
{'q': 2, 'a': 'sf'},
{'q': 3,
'ans': 'Hello World'},
{'q': 4, 'a': 'johnsmith@gmail.com'},
{'q': 100, 'a': 'YES'}]}]
```

was doing a for loop before i.e.

with dlist, and dict

etc but want this automated? json_normalize doesn't work for some reason..

Comment: add expected output

Comment: this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618801/list-of-dictionaries-and-a-dictionary-within-a-dictionary

Comment: thanks Pygril - that worked! just need to make the long format wide now (which can just be done df_f.pivot(index='_id', columns='q', values='a')

Comment: hmm but then if you have duplicates on _id it breaks.. i.e. {'q': 2, 'a': 'sf'}, {'q': 2, 'a': 'hello'}, >>> any way to fix this quick?